# Are there any Markdown plugins for TWiki?

Tags: markdown, twiki

I'm trying to find a [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) plugin that would allow me to switch to Markdown syntax inside a [TWiki](http://twiki.org/) instance, for just one page at a time or even more fine-grained inside a page by using some kind of syntax that introduces a Markdown block and ends it.

Example:

````
<markdown>
## A heading

```
Here goes some code
```
</markdown>
````

Is there such a thing for TWiki? I searched a bit and couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~skyend/Markdown-Foswiki-0.04/lib/Markdown/Foswiki.pm does this for Foswiki which forked from Twiki.